# how to resize textlabel in a tableview cell

Tags: ios, imageview, tableview, cell, textlabel

I'm programming an app that is containing a RSS reader. The rss reader is downloading a title, description and a image. The image I placed in the accessoryview in the same cell as the description. The description is placed in a textlabel and resize perfectly to the image. But i would like the image to be displayed in the left side. But when i remove the images from the accessoryview and move it to the image to the left side the Textlabel doesn't resize.

How do i resize the textlabel.

```
CGRect f = cell.textLabel.frame;
[cell.textLabel setFrame: CGRectMake(f.origin.x-20, f.origin.y, f.size.width-50, f.size.height)];

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines =3;
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.7];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I have tried to resize it with the setframe function but that doesn't work.

Hope there are some of you that can push me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass the UITableViewCell class.  Here is an example:

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomerCell : UITableViewCell

@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "MyCustomerCell.h"

@implementation MyCustomerCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,150,90);
    self.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 90);
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(250, 0, 200, 40);   //change this to your needed
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(250, 40, 200, 40);
}
```

@end

Comment: How do i then implement it in my tableview?

Comment: In the class that you have tableview:
1.  Import the header file: #import "MyCustomerCell.h".
2.  Anywhere that you define the cell use: MyCustomerCell *cell = ... instead of the normal UITableViewCell *cell = ...

Comment: Thanks mate - that toke care of my problem :)

Comment: Why do we need to do this? Does no one have access to the UITableViewCell class frame or bounds normally?